# Text Editor with designMode. How to force designMode to use HTML tags instead of spans

Tags: javascript, iframe, editor, designmode

I've build a small text editor with an iframe and designMode. (here is an example NOT coded by me http://jsfiddle.net/Kxmaf/6/. I've found it here on Stackoverflow).

If I retrieve the content of the iframe (`document.body.innerHTML`) the result is something like this: `<span style="font-weight: bold;">Test</span> Text <span style="font-style: italic;">Text</span> <span style="text-decoration: underline;">TT</span>`

Is it possible to set the designMode to use tags instead of spans with style attribute?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

In most browsers (but not IE), you can use the "StyleWithCSS" command to switch between style modes, allowing you to choose between styling using elements such as `<b>` and `<i>` or styling using `<span>` elements with style attributes. You can do this using the the "StyleWithCSS" command, falling back to "UseCSS" in older browsers. The following switches commands to use the non-CSS version:

```
try {
    if (!document.execCommand("StyleWithCSS", false, useCss)) {
        // The value required by UseCSS is the inverse of what you'd expect
        document.execCommand("UseCSS", false, !useCss);
    }
} catch (ex) {
    // IE doesn't recognise these commands and throws.
}
```